# Troubleshooting TS2345 Error when building Loopback 4 application with JWT Authentication

Tags: loopbackjs, jwt

I'm try to integrate JWT authentication into my loopback 4 application. Right now I've been following the documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html) and the [shopping tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html), but I'm getting a strange build error when I'm registering my authentication strategy.

Here's my application.ts:

```
export class Application extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options?: ApplicationConfig) {
    super(options);

    this.setUpBindings();

    this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
    registerAuthenticationStrategy(this, JWTAuthenticationStrategy);
    this.sequence(MySequence);

    // Set up default home page
    this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));

    this.component(RestExplorerComponent);

    this.projectRoot = __dirname;
    // Customize @loopback/boot Booter Conventions here
    this.bootOptions = {
      controllers: {
        // Customize ControllerBooter Conventions here
        dirs: ['controllers'],
        extensions: ['.controller.js'],
        nested: true,
      },
    };
  }

  setUpBindings(): void {
    // my bindings
  }
}
```

The build script in my package.json (using @loopback/build)

```
"build": "lb-tsc -p tsconfig.build.json --target es2017 --outDir dist"
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
npm run build =>

src/application.ts:71:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'.
  Type 'Application' is not assignable to type 'Context'.
    Property 'registry' is protected but type 'Context' is not a class derived from 'Context'.

registerAuthenticationStrategy(this, JWTAuthenticationStrategy);
```

I am on Windows 10 using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem.
I was able to resolve by updating the @ loopback / context dependency to the latest version through the command:

`npm install --save @loopback/context`

With the updated dependency the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3281#issuecomment-507510529) where you change `registerAuthenticationStrategy(this, JWTAuthenticationStrategy);` to `registerAuthenticationStrategy(this as any, JWTAuthenticationStrategy);`

```
export class Application extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options?: ApplicationConfig) {
    super(options);

    this.setUpBindings();

    this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
    registerAuthenticationStrategy(this as any, JWTAuthenticationStrategy);
    this.sequence(MySequence);

    // Set up default home page
    this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));

    this.component(RestExplorerComponent);

    this.projectRoot = __dirname;
    // Customize @loopback/boot Booter Conventions here
    this.bootOptions = {
      controllers: {
        // Customize ControllerBooter Conventions here
        dirs: ['controllers'],
        extensions: ['.controller.js'],
        nested: true,
      },
    };
  }

  setUpBindings(): void {
    // my bindings
  }
}
```

This fix worked for me.